# Is there a way to have subscriptions with Stripe and Firebase in Python/Flask?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments, subscription

I was wondering how I would go on about integrating Stripe and Firebase with Python. All of the documentation is written in JS, so I'm quite unsure how to integrate the two. I have an authentication system ready with Firebase itself, I just have to integrate Stripe.

Thanks

I created an authentication system with Firebase, but am unsure how to integrate it with Stripe using Python. My back-end is in Python.